# Analysing Positions in Databases with a program

Tags: engines, database, programming

I've got two questions. I'm wondering if:

1. It is possible to search for certain positions in a database (like Chessbase) and display all of them in a text file.
2. To be able to assign a score to each position automatically with a chess engine.

I've got some notions of programming but I wouldn't mind getting some ideas on how to write such a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html):

> ... FEN positional matches with -t ...

2. Use [ChessArtist](https://github.com/fsmosca/chess-artist). It supports any UCI chess engine, including Stockfish and Komodo.

Comment: It looks good. I just wanted to know if it is possible to deal with FEN instead of PGNs for both?

Comment: @A.Napster My solution is not perfect. pgn-extract doesn't hook up with chess engine, and chess artist doesn't search. But there is nothing stopping you incorporating both in a script.

Comment: I know. my question is whether both can deal with or output FEN

Comment: @A.Napster pgn-extract can deal with FEN by itself. ChessArtist doesn't handle FEN, but it's easy to add.

Comment: Just a thumbs up to say that I managed to what I wanted with the programs you suggested. The only modification was writing the FEN as EPD then analysing with ChessArtist. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/) and, as has been pointed out, it doesn't hook up directly with a chess engine. However, if you would like to try out something I recently wrote that does interface with an engine then there is a description of a [UCI-based analyser](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/chessplag/) that can output annotated PGN via its --annotatePGN option. It is still a little experimental and you will need to compile from source but it might provide something close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and program. However I've already managed to do the job with pgn-extract and ChessArtist. First I extract FEN with pgn-extract , write it in an epd format file then I analyse them  with ChessArtist using Stockfish. It doesn't look pretty but it works like a charm.

Comment: I am glad you have a solution.